# Getting Pygments to work for my cell results

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pygments

I use Jupyter Notebooks to implement and document changes that apply to our production databases.  I program in Python and submit typical SQL statements to the server to fetch results and make changes.

I like to print the sql as part of the cell output for verbose log of the change.  I wanted pygments to help colorize the output so that the SQL would look as nice as possible.

Seems that pygments uses css and I don't know how to get it included

```py
    from pygments import highlight
    from pygments.lexers import SqlLexer
    from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
    from IPython.display import display, HTML
    
    sql_string = '''
    SELECT id, name
      FROM users
     WHERE name between 'B' AND 'P'
    LIMIT 50
    '''

    display(HTML(data=highlight(sql_string, SqlLexer(), HtmlFormatter())))
    display(highlight(sql_string, SqlLexer(), HtmlFormatter()))

    display(HtmlFormatter().get_style_defs('.highlight'))
```

output

```
SELECT id, name
  FROM users
 WHERE name between 'B' AND 'P'
LIMIT 50
u'<div class="highlight"><pre><span></span><span class="k">SELECT</span> <span class="n">id</span><span class="p">,</span> <span class="n">name</span>\n  <span class="k">FROM</span> <span class="n">users</span>\n <span class="k">WHERE</span> <span class="n">name</span> <span class="k">between</span> <span class="s1">&#39;B&#39;</span> <span class="k">AND</span> <span class="s1">&#39;P&#39;</span>\n<span class="k">LIMIT</span> <span class="mi">50</span>\n</pre></div>\n'

'.highlight .hll { background-color: #ffffcc }\n.highlight  { background: #f8f8f8; }\n.highlight .c { color: #408080; font-style: italic } /* Comment */\n.highlight .err { border: 1px solid #FF0000 } /* Error */\n.highlight .k { color: #008000; font-weight: bold } /* Keyword */\n.highlight .o { color: #666666 } /* Operator */\n.highlight .ch { color: #408080; font-style: italic } /* Comment.Hashbang */\n.highlight .cm { color: #408080; font-style: italic } /* Comment.Multiline */\n.highlight .cp { color: #BC7A00 } /* Comment.Preproc */\n.highlight .cpf { color: #408080; font-style: italic } /* Comment.PreprocFile */\n.highlight .c1 { color: #408080; font-style: italic } /* Comment.Single */\n.highlight .cs { color: #408080; font-style: italic } /* Comment.Special */\n.highlight .gd { color: #A00000 } /* Generic.Deleted */\n.highlight .ge { font-style: italic } /* Generic.Emph */\n.highlight .gr { color: #FF0000 } /* Generic.Error */\n.highlight .gh { color: #000080; font-weight: bold } /* Generic.Heading */\n.highlight .gi { color: #00A000 } /* Generic.Inserted */\n.highlight .go { color: #888888 } /* Generic.Output */\n.highlight .gp { color: #000080; font-weight: bold } /* Generic.Prompt */\n.highlight .gs { font-weight: bold } /* Generic.Strong */\n.highlight .gu { color: #800080; font-weight: bold } /* Generic.Subheading */\n.highlight .gt { color: #0044DD } /* Generic.Traceback */\n.highlight .kc { color: #008000; font-weight: bold } /* Keyword.Constant */\n.highlight .kd { color: #008000; font-weight: bold } /* Keyword.Declaration */\n.highlight .kn { color: #008000; font-weight: bold } /* Keyword.Namespace */\n.highlight .kp { color: #008000 } /* Keyword.Pseudo */\n.highlight .kr { color: #008000; font-weight: bold } /* Keyword.Reserved */\n.highlight .kt { color: #B00040 } /* Keyword.Type */\n.highlight .m { color: #666666 } /* Literal.Number */\n.highlight .s { color: #BA2121 } /* Literal.String */\n.highlight .na { color: #7D9029 } /* Name.Attribute */\n.highlight .nb { color: #008000 } /* Name.Builtin */\n.highlight .nc { color: #0000FF; font-weight: bold } /* Name.Class */\n.highlight .no { color: #880000 } /* Name.Constant */\n.highlight .nd { color: #AA22FF } /* Name.Decorator */\n.highlight .ni { color: #999999; font-weight: bold } /* Name.Entity */\n.highlight .ne { color: #D2413A; font-weight: bold } /* Name.Exception */\n.highlight .nf { color: #0000FF } /* Name.Function */\n.highlight .nl { color: #A0A000 } /* Name.Label */\n.highlight .nn { color: #0000FF; font-weight: bold } /* Name.Namespace */\n.highlight .nt { color: #008000; font-weight: bold } /* Name.Tag */\n.highlight .nv { color: #19177C } /* Name.Variable */\n.highlight .ow { color: #AA22FF; font-weight: bold } /* Operator.Word */\n.highlight .w { color: #bbbbbb } /* Text.Whitespace */\n.highlight .mb { color: #666666 } /* Literal.Number.Bin */\n.highlight .mf { color: #666666 } /* Literal.Number.Float */\n.highlight .mh { color: #666666 } /* Literal.Number.Hex */\n.highlight .mi { color: #666666 } /* Literal.Number.Integer */\n.highlight .mo { color: #666666 } /* Literal.Number.Oct */\n.highlight .sb { color: #BA2121 } /* Literal.String.Backtick */\n.highlight .sc { color: #BA2121 } /* Literal.String.Char */\n.highlight .sd { color: #BA2121; font-style: italic } /* Literal.String.Doc */\n.highlight .s2 { color: #BA2121 } /* Literal.String.Double */\n.highlight .se { color: #BB6622; font-weight: bold } /* Literal.String.Escape */\n.highlight .sh { color: #BA2121 } /* Literal.String.Heredoc */\n.highlight .si { color: #BB6688; font-weight: bold } /* Literal.String.Interpol */\n.highlight .sx { color: #008000 } /* Literal.String.Other */\n.highlight .sr { color: #BB6688 } /* Literal.String.Regex */\n.highlight .s1 { color: #BA2121 } /* Literal.String.Single */\n.highlight .ss { color: #19177C } /* Literal.String.Symbol */\n.highlight .bp { color: #008000 } /* Name.Builtin.Pseudo */\n.highlight .vc { color: #19177C } /* Name.Variable.Class */\n.highlight .vg { color: #19177C } /* Name.Variable.Global */\n.highlight .vi { color: #19177C } /* Name.Variable.Instance */\n.highlight .il { color: #666666 } /* Literal.Number.Integer.Long */'
```

as you can see the output is well marked with the class for the formats and I can fetch the data for the style,   Does anyone know how to get it all to work in a notebook?  Just to be clear the issue is I want to see color in the cell results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Jupyter Notebook, you can also use `IPython.display.Code`

```py
from IPython.display import Code
Code('print("Hello World")', language='python')
```

It won't run as expected in Jupyter Lab though, as documented in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11747), so you'll need to run the following bit there:

```py
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
from IPython.core.display import HTML

formatter = HtmlFormatter()

display(HTML(f'<style>{ formatter.get_style_defs(".highlight") }</style>'))
```

Comment: both of your answers were great but this one showed me a feature that was an even better fit for my original goal.

Answer (score 2):

```py
    from pygments import highlight
    from pygments.lexers import SqlLexer
    from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
    from IPython.core.display import HTML

    sql_string = '''
    SELECT id, name
      FROM users
     WHERE name between 'B' AND 'P'
    LIMIT 50
    '''

    display(HTML("""
    <style>
    {pygments_css}
    </style>
    """.format(pygments_css=HtmlFormatter().get_style_defs('.highlight'))))
    display(HTML(data=highlight(sql_string, SqlLexer(), HtmlFormatter())))
```

Props to digging deeper on Stack Exchange. Found things in an unaccepted question about how to add to the css for jupyter.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly execute the terminal command in the notebook cells:

```
!pygmentize PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE
```