# Highlight Syntax on Notebook running GLSL

Tags: javascript, html, jupyter-notebook, glsl

I was wondering if it's possible to have GLSL Syntax Highlighting on a Jupyter Notebook. I installed a lot of VSCode Extensions related with JupyterNotebook, JavaScript, HTML and GLSL and never made it to work. [VSCode Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQsaQ.png)

I am expecting highlight syntax of GLSL variable like "uniform" and "attribute".

Comment: There's a discussion [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/contributing-a-codemirror-mode-for-a-new-language/10481/2?u=fomightez) for a different language that outlines what it takes to add it. Codemirror default doesn't seem to list GLSL, but I see https://github.com/hughsk/glsl-editor . Is there kernel for it already? If not, are you just looking to highlight some code then I'm wondering if [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72660618/8508004) could help since pygments seems to have GLSL already. I don't know about how to fix the line `from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer` though.

Comment: Link to CodeMirror language modes: https://codemirror.net/5/mode/